# Simple conversion of IEnumerable<T> to JSON in Monotouch

Tags: c#, .net, json, xamarin.ios

I'm wondering if there is a logical way of generating a JSON-string out of any `IEnumerable` in Monotouch-JSON. I found `System.Json`-Namespace but it always seems to need a `KeyValuePair` and I don't understand how to use this overloads.

To make things clear: I don't want to convert some WebRequest from JSON to something in .NET. I want the other way like the JsonResult-Conversion in ASP.NET. My favorite would be something like:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "value1", "value2" };
var result = new System.Json.JsonArray(list);
```

So that `result` is something like

```
["value1","value2"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not particularly neat, but this works:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "value1", "value2" };

var result = new System.Json.JsonArray(list.Select(x => (System.Json.JsonValue)x));

Console.WriteLine( result.ToString() );
```

Answer (score 4):

[Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) would give the output you expect

```
var list = new List<string>() { "value1", "value2" };
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Comment: I've heard that Json.Net has got some problems on iOS-Devices. Do you or @Justin know something about that?

Comment: but what does this say about iOS? Is this statement portable? If you someone uses it on iOS it would be ok for me too, but I read about issues on some other thread.

Comment: @sprinter252 It says, It is stable enough. Can you post where you have read its *concrete* problems with iOS?

Comment: I'll try to find it. Hang on!

Answer (score 3):

The best option (for both compatibility and ease of use) would probably be to go with [Newtonsoft's JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) library.

Comment: Thanks. Please take a look at my comment on @L.B.!